# Read "/proc" to know if a process has opened a port

Tags: linux, tcp, proc, open-files

I need to know if a process with a given PID has opened a port without using external commands.
I must then use the `/proc` filesystem. I can read the `/proc/$PID/net/tcp` file for example and get information about TCP ports opened by the process. However, on a multithreaded process, the `/proc/$PID/task/$TID` directory will also contains a `net/tcp` file. My question is :

do I need to go over all the threads `net/tcp` files, or will the port opened by threads be written into the process `net/tcp` file.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> I can read the /proc/$PID/net/tcp file for example and get information about TCP ports opened by the process.

That file is not a list of tcp ports opened by the *process*. It is a list of all open tcp ports in the current network namespace, and for processes running in the same network namespace is *identical* to the contents of `/proc/net/tcp`.

To find ports opened by your process, you would need to get a list of socket descriptors from `/proc/<pid>/fd`, and then match those descriptors to the `inode` field of `/proc/net/tcp`.

Comment: Thank you, for your answer. And if the process is multithreaded, do I need to go over all the `fd` directory of each thread ? Or does the `/proc/pid/fd` directory "inherit" the `/proc/pid/task/tid/fd` directories ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but that seems like an easy thing to test.

Comment: @rmonjo Threads can't open files, only processes can. The `fd` directory of a thread just repeats the `fd` directory of the process.

Answer (score 13):

Please

```
cat /proc/$PID/net/tcp
```

and you will get output like this

```
  sl  local_address rem_address   st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeout inode
  0: 00000000:01BB 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 2891985097 1 0000000000000000 100 0 0 10 0
```

The second column (`local_address`) of the output shows the port in hexadecimal. Use your Programming Calculator to convert the hex code to decimal.

For example over here, the port :01BB (in hex) is equal to 443 (in decimal) which is the HTTPS default port.

Answer (score 2):

As a side note, the `/proc/net/tcp` has been superseded by the `NETLINK_SOCK_DIAG`, which essentially gives you the same data in a binary form and, from what the implementers say, is faster & safer than reading from the `/proc/...` folder.

There are libraries (`libmnl` is the base library) and the feature is available in many languages (C/C++ can directly access these, Go & Python have extensions, I think perl has too, and certainly many others).

Since you do not say which language you are using, it's difficult to say more at this point. I have a C sample implementation on Stackoverflow here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68425240/can-the-netlink-sock-diag-interface-be-used-to-listen-for-listen-and-close

Comment: "Since you do not say which language you are using, it's difficult to say more at this point." => it's been 6 years don't worry I'm fine . I was looking for a language agnostic solution anyway

Comment: @rmonjo Yes. Others who end up on your question, though, may be interested in using the newer interface available to them.

Answer (score 1):

Here is sample script which discovers inode of socket descriptor and displays PID of running process which has opened this socket.

```
port=9090;
hex_port=$(python -c 'print(hex('$port')[2:])');
inode=$(cat /proc/net/tcp | grep ":$hex_port" | awk '{print $10}');
for i in $(ps axo pid); do  
   ls -l /proc/$i/fd 2> /dev/null | grep -q ":\[$inode\]" &&  echo $i;
done
```

Comment: that's super useful, thank you!

Comment: hex_port=$(printf %x $port)