# Why I can't see port opened by a process in file descriptors?

Tags: proc, file-descriptors

I have a rabbitmq management process running, which opens a port `15672`,

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:15672           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5431/beam
```

As you can see the process has a `PID` of `5431`.

If I go to `/proc/5431` and run `ls fd`, I don't see port `15672` in that list (suppressed output),

```
lr-x------ 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq 64 Sep 12 14:59 0 -> /dev/null
lrwx------ 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq 64 Sep 12 14:59 1 -> socket:[351505]
lrwx------ 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq 64 Sep 12 14:59 12 -> socket:[375420]
lrwx------ 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq 64 Sep 12 14:59 2 -> socket:[351505]
lr-x------ 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq 64 Sep 12 14:59 3 -> /dev/null
lrwx------ 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq 64 Sep 12 14:59 4 -> anon_inode:[eventpoll]
lr-x------ 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq 64 Sep 12 14:59 5 -> pipe:[351690]
lrwx------ 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq 64 Sep 12 14:59 54 -> socket:[351702]
lrwx------ 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq 64 Sep 12 14:59 55 -> socket:[351704]
l-wx------ 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq 64 Sep 12 14:59 6 -> pipe:[351690]
lr-x------ 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq 64 Sep 12 14:59 60 -> pipe:[351726]
l-wx------ 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq 64 Sep 12 14:59 63 -> pipe:[351727]
lrwx------ 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq 64 Sep 12 14:59 68 -> socket:[351740]
lrwx------ 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq 64 Sep 12 14:59 69 -> socket:[351743]
lrwx------ 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq 64 Sep 12 14:59 7 -> anon_inode:[timerfd]
lrwx------ 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq 64 Sep 12 14:59 70 -> socket:[351774]
lrwx------ 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq 64 Sep 12 14:59 71 -> socket:[357375]
lrwx------ 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq 64 Sep 12 14:59 72 -> socket:[351818]
lrwx------ 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq 64 Sep 12 14:59 8 -> socket:[351698]
lrwx------ 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq 64 Sep 12 14:59 9 -> socket:[357167]
```

Can someone please tell me why port `15672` is not listed there?

Comment: Linking in: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226276/read-proc-to-know-if-a-process-has-opened-a-port

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the fd this way:

```
pid=5431
find /proc/$pid/fd -lname 'socket:\['$(grep 00000000:3D38/proc/$pid/net/tcp|awk '{print $10}')'\]'
```

3D38 is the base-16 equivalent of 15672